# intellij debug: run to cursor ignoring all breakpoints before the cursor

Tags: debugging, intellij-idea

intellij debug: run to cursor ignoring all breakpoints before the cursor. Is there a way? Suppose there are many breakpoints before the cursor, and it is not convenient to disable them one by one.

```
   Line10  <----- breakpoint, stopped here
   ...
   Line50  <----- breakpoint
   ...
-> Line500 <-- cursor
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Force Run to Cursor](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/stepping-through-the-program.html#tips-tricks) command enables you to jump to the cursor position ignoring existing breakpoints on the way.

[image: Force run to cursor]